# Tournament organization that avoids repetitions

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-optimization, combinatorial-designs

A card game is played individually in tables of 4 players. I want to organize a tournament for 24 people. Hence in each round the players are divided into 6 tables. I want organize the tables so that repetitions (two players playing each other more than once) are avoided as far as possible.

I have two questions:

What is the maximum number of rounds we can play without any two players playing each other more than once? Of course the answer must be smaller than 8.

Is there an algorithm to obtain such maximal disposition of tables? I find difficult to avoid repetitions heuristically past round 4.

Comment: Rob found $6$ solutions and mike found $24$. My guess is that those are not accidental , they are factorials , $3! = 6$ and $4! = 24$. But maybe I am missing something ...

Comment: @mick I found a $6$-round solution, and Mike found a $5$-round solution.  Both are schedules for the $24$ given players.

Comment: @RobPratt yes you found 6(!) 6 round solutions and mike 24(!) 5 round solutions. I assume those 6 and 24 are the maximum possible.

Comment: No @mick, you are misinterpreting the results. Mike and I showed one solution each.  Mike showed one row per person and one column per round.  I showed one row per round.

Comment: @RobPratt oh thanks sorry. So how many solutions are there ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Six rounds are possible:

```
{1,6,12,23} {5,11,18,24} {4,9,15,22} {2,10,13,19} {7,14,17,21} {3,8,16,20}
{1,16,19,22} {2,5,12,14} {3,7,11,13} {8,9,18,23} {6,15,17,24} {4,10,20,21}
{1,5,9,13} {2,11,17,23} {4,6,16,18} {3,15,19,21} {8,10,14,22} {7,12,20,24}
{1,7,10,18} {5,15,20,23} {2,9,16,21} {4,8,13,24} {6,11,14,19} {3,12,17,22}
{1,2,3,4} {5,6,7,8} {9,10,11,12} {13,14,15,16} {17,18,19,20} {21,22,23,24}
{1,8,11,15} {5,10,16,17} {12,13,18,21} {3,9,14,24} {4,7,19,23} {2,6,20,22}
```

Seven rounds are optimal:

```
{1,2,3,4} {5,6,7,8} {9,10,11,12} {13,14,15,16} {17,18,19,20} {21,22,23,24}
{1,6,12,24} {2,7,16,23} {3,11,14,19} {4,15,20,22} {5,9,18,21} {8,10,13,17}
{1,9,13,23} {2,8,11,20} {3,7,17,22} {4,6,14,21} {5,12,15,19} {10,16,18,24}
{1,11,18,22} {2,6,9,15} {3,8,12,16} {4,10,19,23} {5,14,17,24} {7,13,20,21}
{1,7,10,14} {2,12,17,21} {3,9,20,24} {4,5,11,13} {6,16,19,22} {8,15,18,23}
{1,8,19,21} {2,5,10,22} {3,6,13,18} {4,9,16,17} {7,11,15,24} {12,14,20,23}
{1,5,16,20} {2,13,19,24} {3,10,15,21} {4,7,12,18} {6,11,17,23} {8,9,14,22}
```

Comment: So cool @RobPratt. What algorithm/software are you using?

Comment: I am using the mixed integer linear programming solver in SAS.

Answer (score 0):

This is a special case of the Social Golfer Problem. Using the web page [Good Enough Golfers](https://goodenoughgolfers.com/), I found a five-round solution. I was unable to find a six-round solution, but this does not rule out the possibility of a six-round solution.

|  | Round 1 | Round 2 | Round 3 | Round 4 | Round 5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | Group 6 | Group 4 | Group 2 | Group 6 | Group 2 |
| B | Group 3 | Group 5 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 4 |
| C | Group 5 | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 2 | Group 3 |
| D | Group 2 | Group 2 | Group 5 | Group 5 | Group 4 |
| E | Group 1 | Group 4 | Group 3 | Group 1 | Group 6 |
| F | Group 1 | Group 5 | Group 4 | Group 6 | Group 5 |
| G | Group 4 | Group 1 | Group 6 | Group 6 | Group 3 |
| H | Group 1 | Group 1 | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 2 |
| I | Group 3 | Group 6 | Group 3 | Group 5 | Group 2 |
| J | Group 2 | Group 6 | Group 2 | Group 2 | Group 6 |
| K | Group 4 | Group 4 | Group 5 | Group 2 | Group 1 |
| L | Group 3 | Group 3 | Group 4 | Group 4 | Group 3 |
| M | Group 4 | Group 2 | Group 4 | Group 1 | Group 2 |
| N | Group 5 | Group 6 | Group 1 | Group 6 | Group 4 |
| O | Group 5 | Group 1 | Group 4 | Group 3 | Group 6 |
| P | Group 1 | Group 2 | Group 2 | Group 4 | Group 1 |
| Q | Group 4 | Group 3 | Group 1 | Group 5 | Group 5 |
| R | Group 2 | Group 3 | Group 3 | Group 3 | Group 1 |
| S | Group 6 | Group 6 | Group 5 | Group 3 | Group 3 |
| T | Group 2 | Group 4 | Group 6 | Group 4 | Group 5 |
| U | Group 3 | Group 1 | Group 5 | Group 1 | Group 5 |
| V | Group 6 | Group 5 | Group 1 | Group 4 | Group 6 |
| W | Group 6 | Group 3 | Group 6 | Group 1 | Group 4 |
| X | Group 5 | Group 5 | Group 6 | Group 5 | Group 1 |